# Registering a jailbroken development device

Tags: iphone, ipad, development-environment, jailbreak, provisioning-profile

The few posts I've found regarding this issue are quite old or not concluding about it... is there any problem in registering a jailbroken iPhone/iPad for development, and then proceeding normally creating the provisioning profiles and so on? May this depend on the Xcode version or iOS version used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with registering a jailbroken device for development. I've used many with my iTunes Connect account \ Member center etc'. Got nothing to do with the Xcode version \ iOS version.

A small edit, Having a JailBroken Device is not all good though. I've experienced a lot of weird behavior when using a Jailbroken device with installed tweaks and Xcode, for example, if you'll install the tweak PhotoAlbums+ from Cydia you won't be able to run your apps on the device while it's connected to Xcode.

Comment: I believe your problems (at least this one) are a result of the tweaks you install, not the jailbreaking itself.

Comment: Of course its a result of tweaks you install. I even mentioned the name of the problematic tweak. There's no point having a jailbroken device without any tweaks on it. My point is that you won't expect that a tweak you install from cydia will cause problems and won't let you run your code on your phone from Xcode. (I've edited my answer to be more clear)

Comment: *There's no point having a jailbroken device without any tweaks* ... that's 100% false.  SO is a **developer** site, not a user site.  I jailbreak my phones to get ssh access, allow me to install the apps I write to `/Applications`, get `root` privileges, install UNIX command line tools from Cydia, and facilitate reverse engineering of undocumented features, or to understand better how iOS works.  None of those have anything to do with tweaks.  Your problem is installing garbage software written by people who don't know what they're doing.  Not by jailbreaking.  -1 for conflation and attitude.

Comment: I'm guessing that a broken command line tool you install from cydia can cause the same problems as a "tweak". Bottom line is that you alter the OS and that can cause problems. No need to get angry, it's all good. :)

Comment: No, I disagree again.  Most of the command line tools from Cydia are published by Saurik himself, and he knows what he's doing.  Most tweaks are written by people with much less expertise.  The fundamental technology that *tweaks* rely on is also very error-prone.  Injecting new code into existing apps (which you didn't write or have source code for) by *method swizzling* is error-prone.  It's a nice feature, and you couldn't do many things without it.  But, that doesn't change the fact that it's an unstable technique, especially in the hands of developers of modest skill levels.